# iPad cannot reach website from other computer via internal IP, except after a DHCP + getpacket command on other computer

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ipad

I find this really weird, and maybe you know potential theoretical reasons as to why this is. Whenever I type on my iPad `192.168.178.xxx` where `xxx` are the final digits of the internal IP of my laptop, then my iPad is almost always unable to load the website.

However, when I go to my laptop and type in:

```
sudo ipconfig set en0 DHCP
```

And then this a few seconds later:

```
ipconfig getpacket en0
```

then it will reload the website, but only if I send a new HTTP request, the old request will still fail.

In all these cases, my laptop gets the same internal IP, so I'm a bit stumped as to why this works.

I'm happy that this works, but would like to expand my understanding as to why it works. What would be your guess to what my router doing?

Comment: @Tetsujin I disagree since this seems to be a networking question.

Comment: It is a networking question.

Comment: Are you sure your laptop is the _only_ device with this IP address? Can you install arping & tcpdump and check?